# ajax yii neverending loading

Tags: ajax, yii

I am trying to use ajax in yii but sometimes loading doesn't stop in my browser, does anybody know why?

here is my code, I know it is not the best solution but it works (except neverending loading in google chrome)

```
<script>           
        function refresh(){
<?
echo CHtml::ajax(array('url' => CController::createUrl('results/UpdateAjax'), 'update' => '#data'
    , 'complete' => 'function(html){refresh()}'
))
?>

    }
</script>

Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('firstRefresh', "$(document).ready(function () {" .
            CHtml::ajax(array('url' => CController::createUrl('results/UpdateAjax'), 'update' => '#data'
                , 'complete' => 'function(html){refresh()}'
            ))
            . "});", CClientScript::POS_READY);
```

Comment: Can you provide an url or something to test? is there any error in the console? And, when you call register script and pass CClientScript::POS_READY you don't need to wrap your js code into $(document).ready because CClientScript::POS_READY do that for you

Comment: I've just tried it without $(document).ready and it didn't work, unfortunately this is all I can provide, there is no error in the console everything seems alright except that that it is still loading

Comment: Have you tried CHtml::ajaxLink? http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#ajaxLink-detail that's what i use to deal with links that call my backend ans works with no problems

Comment: CHtml::ajaxLink is something different, I don't want user to click anywhere, it should refresh content automatically asap